# Using CURL command to press an HTML button (speed test)

Tags: macos, unix, html

I’m trying to use a Linux CURL command to press a “Start Test” button on a Speed Test website in order to grab the speed data.

Context:

I’m using this approach rather than installing the speedtest-cli app because this will be part of a script that gets installed on multiple endpoints. The speed test website is:
https://www.speedcheck.org/

I’m trying to follow [this example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88825/press-a-html-button-via-shell-script) .
When I inspect the HTML element, it reveals:

```
<a _ngcontent-dhl-c4="" class="btn start-button" data-wow-delay="0.7s">Start Test</a>
```

…but this does not match the format of the example link on the StackExchange example.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a complete novice in Applescript but when I tried to run the above script using Apple script editor I get the error: error "Safari got an error: You must enable the 'Allow JavaScript from Apple Events' option in Safari's Develop menu to use 'do JavaScript'."  < -- I can't seem to find a resolution or "how to" for this error.

Comment: Excellent! That worked. Thanks so much. I learning something new today. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternate answer to using `curl`, I'd use **AppleScript**, e.g.:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Safari"
    tell current tab of window 1
        do JavaScript ¬
            "document.getElementsByClassName('btn start-button')[0].click();"
    end tell
end tell
```

**Or:**

```applescript
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript ¬
        "document.getElementsByClassName('btn start-button')[0].click();" in document 1
end tell
```

**Notes:**

This requires **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** to be check on the hidden **Develop** menu.

To unhide the hidden **Develop** menu:

- **Safari** > **Preferences…** > **Advanced** > **[√] Show Develop menu in menu bar**

---

For **Google Chrome** there would be some minor changes to the *code*, e.g.:

Change `current tab` to `active tab` and change `do JavaScript` to `execute javascript`

Then click **Google Chrome** > **View** > **Developer** > **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events**, if applicable to the version of **Google Chrome** you are running.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>